# Interfaces designed deliberately to contain high density of content and actions

Tags: user-research, interface, research, usability-study, expert-interface

There has been a strong trend towards the simplification and shallow IA of modern websites and applications, yet I can't help but wonder if there is also some correction required for certain applications that have been oversimplified and as a result reduced its utility and usability for the user.

I am specifically referring to applications that require expert training and knowledge, and some examples include control systems for water or power plants, software to monitor and optimize mining operations, visualization and search tools for scientists, trading platforms for financial institutions, etc.

Has anyone out there worked on complex systems requiring the design of dense content and functions? Has the simplification of the original interface design resulted in a loss of 'user-friendliness' that was not expected?

I am interested any research or examples to would illustrate or highlight situations where complex interfaces are actual more beneficial.

Comment: This isn't a good question for this site. You're asking for case studies. It's a really interesting topic, but not something with a simple 'correct' answer. That said, just an anecdote for you: I used to be a part of a small software firm that catered to a niche market that had been dominated by a DOS application for decades. We came up with a much friendlier UI but could never win over existing customers of the old system because they have invested so much into learning the command line functionality of it.

Answer (score 1):

[ISO9241-11](http://www.usabilitynet.org/tools/r_international.htm#9241-11) defines usability as:

"The extent to which a product can be used by specified users to achieve specified goals with **effectiveness**, **efficiency** and **satisfaction** in a specified context of use."

You will note that the word *simplification* is not mentioned at all in this definition.

Usability is about:

- **Effectiveness** - can users complete tasks, achieve goals with the product, i.e. do what they want to do?
- **Efficiency** - how much effort do users require to do this? (Often measured in time)
- **Satisfaction** – what do users think about the products ease of use?

….which are affected by:

- **The users** - who is using the product? e.g. are they highly trained and experienced users, or novices?
- **Their goals** - what are the users trying to do with the product - does it support what they want to do with it?
- **The usage situation** (or 'context of use') - where and how is the product being used?

So you are unlikely to find case studies, but the bottom line is complicated systems need complicated user interfaces.

However, complex systems can still be usable. Complexity is not the same as  Confusion, because it is confusing interfaces which cause usability problems, not complex interfaces.